# How do I take a column from a data set, and test it against the max of another column?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am currently working in the package nyclflights13, data set flights. There is a column for the name of a plane, and a column for how many times that plane flew. I want to know which plane flew the most amount of times. Also I would like to omit any missing values, ie any NA;s.

I know that I am going to have to use the summarise () function and the select function with a - to omit the missing values. I'm just not sure how to do that exactly.

Comment: Are you asking which value of tailnum had the most flights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code to tally the number of rows in `flights` with each value of `tailnum`.

```
library(magrittr)
library(nycflights13)
data(flights)

flights %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(tailnum) %>% 
  dplyr::tally() %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(desc(n))
```

You can then ignore the top row when examining the results, as it is for `NA` values of `tailnum`.

Comment: To remove the top row - with NAs - add to my code, at the end, ` %>% dplyr::filter(!is.na(tailnum))`

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it necessary to put "dplyr::" every time, or can I just do "library(tidyverse)" and then omit the "dplyr::"? Also, in that last line "dplyr::arrange(desc(n))" you just put "n" as your argument. How does it know that "n" refers to the number of flights?

Comment: Yes, you can use `library(dplyr)` if you wish, or even `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: `n` is part of the output of `tally`.

Comment: `tally`, here, counts the number of rows with each value of `tailnum`.